# How to read data using JSONP, Ajax and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to read data from this API, but it is not working, I have an input box where I enter the isbn number and then get the data, using jsonp. Could you possibly help me in identifying where my error("Cannot read property 'title' of undefined") is?

```
function add(){
        var isbn = parseInt($("#isbn").val());
        var list = $("#list");
        console.log(parseInt(isbn));

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=" + isbn + "&jscmd=details&callback=mycallback",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(isbn){
                var infoUrl = isbn.info_url;
                var thumbnailUrl = isbn.thumbnail_url;
                var title = isbn.details.title;
                var publishers = isbn.details.publishers;
                var isbn13 = isbn.details.isbn_13;


                console.log(isbn.info_url);
                              }
        });
    }
```

Comment: First do `console.log(isbn)` to see what information is available.

Comment: @AI.G the same thing...

Comment: Did you comment out/delete the variable declarations to prevent the error and see the result? I mean: `success: function(isbn) { console.log(isbn); }` without anything inside.

Comment: @AI.G Now, I did, and the data is a bit weird: Object
__proto__
:
Object
__defineGetter__
:
__defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__
:
__defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__
:
__lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__
:
__lookupSetter__()
constructor
:
Object()
hasOwnProperty
:
hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf
:
isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable
:
propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString
:
toLocaleString()
toString
:
toString()
valueOf
:
valueOf()
get __proto__
:
__proto__()
set __proto__
:
__proto__()

Comment: @MT console.log(isbn) the comment all those var infoUrl = isbn.info_url; etc..

Comment: @AI.G so it's not the data that I need to get...

Comment: @M.T are you in tab console of firebug ?

Comment: @jemz I don't understand?

Comment: @M.T is that the result of console.log(isbn) ? did you click the console tab of firebug ?

Comment: @M.T try this console.log(isbn.info_url); and tell us what is the result of console

Comment: No, I am using the console of google chrome.

Comment: @jemz, it prints undefined...

Comment: @jemz any idea what I should do?

Comment: @M.T if undefined maybe your url is wrong or lack some parameter ? check it again your url

Comment: @M.T can you just manual put the value of isbn in your url.and see the result of console.log(isbn)

Comment: @jemz, the url is okay, I tried using an actual isbn: https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=0439023483&jscmd=details&callback=mycallback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a professor, and this is how she told me to solve it:

```
function add(){
    var isbn = parseInt($("#isbn").val());
    var list = $("#list");
    console.log(parseInt(isbn));

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=" + isbn + "&jscmd=details&callback=mycallback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data){
            var thumb=data["ISBN:"+isbn+""].thumbnail_url;
             ....
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Open Library's API](https://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/api/books) expects `bibkeys` to be prefixed with their type and a colon, rather than just the number alone:

```
function add(){
    var isbn = 'ISBN:' + $("#isbn").val();
    // ...
```

The colon also means the value should be URL-encoded, which jQuery can do for you:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?jscmd=details&callback=?",
    data: { bidkeys: isbn },
    dataType: "jsonp",
```

Then, the data it returns reuses the `bibkeys` you provided as properties:

```
{ "ISBN:0123456789": { "info_url": ..., "details": { ... }, ... } }
```

To access the book's information, you'll have to first access this property:

```
success: function(data){
    var bookInfo = data[isbn];

    console.log(bookInfo.details.title);
    // etc.
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/3p6s7051/

---

You can also retrieve the `bibkey` from the object itself using `Object.keys()`:

```
success: function (data) {
    var bibkey = Object.keys(data)[0];
    var bookInfo = data[bibkey];

    console.log(bookInfo.details.title);
    // ...
}
```

> Note: You can use this to validate, since the request can be technically successful and not include any book information (i.e. no matches found):
>
> ```
> success: function (data) {
>     var bibkeys = Object.keys(data);
>
>     if (bibkeys.length === 0)
>         return showError('No books were found with the ISBN provided.');
>
>     // ...
> ```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/q0aqys87/

Comment: Thanks for your reply but, I am trying this too, and I am getting the same error.

Comment: I tried printing only the bookInfo part and I am getting underfined.

Comment: @M.T I've updated my answer with a few notes from the API's docs. Also included an example JSFiddle.

Comment: Hey  Jonathan, sorry but still it is not working... and thanks!